# Trying to figure out if a certain website text animation is done with a certain library or plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, text

If you look at this website and let it load a bit http://visage.co/, you'll notice the text keeps changing and it has some freaking awesome transitions. I figured this is mostly done with some jquery but I was seeing if anyone here has any experience and what they would recommend in recreating something of this sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are looking for something like this http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/. The page also has some demos from other websites. This would be one way of recreating it.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty darn close to it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please check http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/ it is the best library for parallax content in my opinion.

Comment: Almost, this is more on par with activating object animations on scroll. I need to be able to modify individual characters.